# Show that for $n\geq 3$, there exists a nonabelian group with $2n$ elements that is generated by two elements of order 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that for $n\geq 3$, there exists a nonabelian group with $2n$ elements that is generated by two elements of order $2$.

I know how to show it with a Cayley diagraph, but how do I show it without one?

Comment: Consider the dihedral group $D_n = \langle r,s: r^n = s^2 = e, rs = sr^{-1}\rangle$. Show $rs$ and $s$ generate this group.

Comment: Please make the body of the Question self-contained, not relying wholly on the title to pose a problem.  Expanding on what you are able to do with a "Cayley diagraph" would improve the Question and give some context for your request to "show it without one".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the dihedral groups.  Define $D_{2n}$ to be the symmetry group of the regular $n$-gon.  $D_{2n}$ has order $2n$, and it is generated by two reflections.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the dihedral group (= symmetry group of a regular $n$-gon)

Comment: Which two elements of order two would generate the dihedral group $D_n$ of order $2n$?  The typical presentation involves one generator of order two (a reflection) and one of order $n$ (a rotation).

Comment: I merely gave hint, it is up to Matt Gaikema to figure out which elements are eligible. But I see that somebody else already gave away the answer.